# Is it feasible to use postgres 9 replication to reduce backup downtime?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

I'm investigating strategies to reduce the maintenance downtime on a critical database. The DB contains bioinformatics data and is accessed by users in many different time zones around the world, 7 days a week (so off peak hours are limited). The database contains 10's of millions of rows and is growing rapidly.

As we are planning to upgrade to pg9, I want to find out if I can perform backups on a slave, so the master isn't affected. I am wondering if I should be very concerned about the slave getting too far behind on the log when a backup is in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database is too big or backups are too slow, you should be using WAL archiving as a backup method.  You don't need PostgreSQL 9.0 for that.  Having WAL archiving is a prerequisite for WAL-based replication, so you'd almost get it for free if you are interested in the replication feature in 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no downtime during backup. Why do you think the database is down?

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html):

> pg_dump does not block other users
>   accessing the database (readers or
>   writers).